# Embed Youtube and Vimeo Videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, vimeo

i trying to embed Video from youtube and vimeo, at the Moment i do the following:

```
    if([item.source  isEqual: @"youtube"])
    {
        UIView *videoContainerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 320.0f)];


        XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:item.videoId];
        [videoPlayerViewController presentInView:videoContainerView];
        [videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
        videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;

        [self addSubview:videoContainerView];

    } else if ([item.source isEqual:@"vimeo"]) {

           [YTVimeoExtractor fetchVideoURLFromURL:item.url quality:YTVimeoVideoQualityMedium completionHandler:^(NSURL *videoURL, NSError *error, YTVimeoVideoQuality quality) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            } else if (videoURL) {
                NSLog(@"Extracted url : %@", [videoURL absoluteString]);

                self.playerView = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
                [self.playerView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
                self.playerView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

                [self addSubview:self.playerView.view];
            }
        }];

    }
```

For youtube Videos im using the XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController, and for Vimeo i´m using YTVimeoExtractor. Now i have two Problems

**First Problem:**

The youtube Part works like charm, but the Vimeo part doesn´t work. From my webserver i get the following url:

```
http://vimeo.com/85004906
```

and after the url gets extracted by the YTVimeoExtractor i have the following snippet:

```
http://pdl.vimeocdn.com/85824/823/226049076.mp4?token2=1393842513_dd8e4d573f67656c80b91b3130d42824&aksessionid=ac7102b713f0b2c0
```

This is the videoUrl which i set into the MPMoviePlayerViewController. But i only get some gray background frame an no video is shown at all

**Second Problem:**

Apples doc says: *If your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming.*

So if i´m not using this, my app will get rejected? And if i have to use http streaming i have to do a extra part for HD Video?

Thanks!

Comment: please explain more what you mean by "Vimeo part not working", where does it fail? do you fail to get response, or you get a wrong URL or you get a null URL ?

Comment: I´ve edit my Post, i hope its better now :)

Answer (score 1):

I checked `YTVimeoExtractor` & it uses a correct technique to extract vimeo videos, and the above url seems correct.

I am not sure why the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` isn't playing the video, but I recommend trying to play it using `AVPlayer` (It isn't as simple as `MPMoviePlayerViewController` but it is more powerful) & check if you get the same result.

Regarding the 5MB limit, you don't have to worry about it, your app will get approved :)